# composer update for Craft 3 to Craft 4

Tags: craft4, composer, updating

Trying to migrate a site from Craft 3 to Craft 4. Carefully followed the instructions to update my composer.json file to reflect the Craft 4 versions of Craft and all plugins. When I run composer update I get this error message:
In CurlDownloader.php line 611:

The "https://composer.craftcms.com/providers/ccraftcms/cms.json" file could
not be downloaded (HTTP/2 404 )

Any wisdom on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hey Roi, would you mind to share your composer.json?

Comment: Hey Max - I gave up and started again from scratch. Now I am able to run composer update, but when I run craft migrate/all after that I get a message saying "No new migrations found. Your system is up to date".  I checked the composer.lock file and it was updated with the new dependencies, so very strange